# Meteor: Accounts.forgotPassword returns internal server error on UAT but not on localhost

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use Accounts.forgotPassword but it gives a 500 Internal Server Error. The error is only shown when it is deployed to the server and not when it is running on the localhost. Does anyone have any idea why is it happening or how should I debug it? Any help will be appreciated.

```
Accounts.forgotPassword({
      email: email
    }, (err, result)=>{
      if(err) console.log(err) 
})
```

Comment: What do the logs on the server say? Also, your question title says `.forgotPassword` but you're using `.sendResetPasswordEmail` in your code. Either way your parameters do not match the API.

Comment: Have you set the `MAIL_URL` environment variable?

Comment: @chazsolo I was just testing .sendResetPasswordEmail. Actual code is .forgotPassword. Sorry about that.

Comment: @FredStark I have something like this:
Meteor.startup(() => {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' +
   encodeURIComponent("*****@gmail.com") + ':' +
   encodeURIComponent("****") + '@' +
   encodeURIComponent("smtp.gmail.com") + ':' + "465/";

Comment: I'm pretty sure changing the vars in node after it's started has no effect

Comment: So what do you think where should I add it? Because it is how the documentation tells us to do it. Thanks in advance! @FredStark

Comment: Where in the docs does it say to do that?!?

Comment: Can't find it: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Adocs.meteor.com+OR+site%3Aguide.meteor.com+"process.env"

Comment: The right place depends on how you're deploying. How are you keeping node running on the server?

Comment: @FredStark I am using mup for deployment

Comment: Have you got `MAIL_URL` in the config under `meteor: { env: {`?

Comment: @FredStark I am able to send the email. I had to change the port number as I am not using SSL but instead I am using TLS. Anyway, thank you for your help.